# Republish a topic data

Tags: ros, gazebo, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

first of all here is my setup : Ubuntu 16.04 with ROS kinetic and Gazebo 7.0.

I have a Scenario where a simulated turtlebot drives to several objects. Actual i need some pointcloud data from him but only from the approach.

I got already some help from jarvisschultz, he helps me with the idea to use `pointcloud_to_pcd` to subscribe a node that only publishs pointcloud data during the approach. My question now is how to republish the pointcloud data from `/depth/points` ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/292574/republish-a-topic-data/) by [Baumboon](https://answers.ros.org/users/32033/baumboon/) on ROS Answers with karma: 206 on 2018-05-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Here's a quick example adapted from the talker.py in the tutorials:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import rospy
from sensor_msgs.msg import PointCloud2
import random

def callback(data, pub):
    # Here would be a place to do some sort of computation to decide if you want
    # the data republished on the new topic. I've inserted a dummy computation.:
    if random.randint(1,10) <= 5:
        rospy.loginfo("republish this cloud!")
        pub.publish(data)
    return
    
def listener():
    rospy.init_node('pointcloud_republisher')
    pub = rospy.Publisher("pcd_points", PointCloud2, queue_size=1)
    rospy.Subscriber("depth/points", PointCloud2, callback, callback_args=(pub))
    rospy.spin()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    listener()
```

The only real differences are:

- In the callback you'd want to decide if this is a topic that you would want published for the `pointcloud_to_pcd` node to save as a pcd file.
- I've used the `callback_args` optional argument to the Subscriber constructor so that we can keep using the same Publisher object for all publishing on the `pcd_points` topic.

---

Originally posted by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) with karma: 9031 on 2018-05-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1